# Building static ffmpeg libraries on amd64 where libc isn't compiled with -fPIC

Tags: 16.04, compiling, ffmpeg

First off, I'm not a C/C++ developer so be specific in your solutions and try to be understanding. Secondly, there is a similar [question here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/498082/what-to-do-with-recompile-with-fpic-message) that does not resolve the issue. Here is my configure line after cloning from the ffmpeg repo:

```
./configure --disable-debug --disable-doc \
            --disable-avdevice --disable-programs \
            --disable-decoders --disable-encoders \
            --disable-filters --disable-muxers \
            --disable-demuxers --disable-indevs \
            --disable-outdevs --disable-swscale-alpha \
            --disable-symver --disable-protocols \
            --disable-bsfs --disable-parsers \
            --disable-symver --disable-iconv \
            --disable-shared --enable-static \
            --enable-swresample --enable-swscale \
            --enable-pthreads --enable-pic \
            --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-asm \
            --enable-yasm --enable-decoder=aac \
            --enable-decoder=h264 --enable-decoder=libspeex \
            --enable-parser=h264,aac --prefix="$(pwd)/linux" \
            --extra-cflags="-fPIC -mcmodel=large" \
            --extra-cxxflags="-fPIC -mcmodel=large" \
            --pkg-config-flags="--static"
```

After that completes I run the following:

```
make clean
make
make install
```

I then copy the *.a files from the linux directory (my output dir, per prefix) into my project's lib folder. I then run my build and end up with this error when it gets to the linking step:

```
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libavcodec.a(hevc_cabac.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `ff_h264_cabac_tables' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am running on Ubuntu 16.04 and cannot use GPL or non-free code for this.

Comment: Seems a little odd running `make distclean` after configure?

Comment: I was actually running distclean before each configure, so that was a mistake